# Angular forms dirty when same as initial state

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm using angular to create a simple input form as below.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way for me to track, what I would call, "true" state of dirty or not if a user changes a controls value then reverts back to original.

So on loading my "name" property = "John".

Then user deletes a character to make name property "Jon"
now my contactForm is dirty.

If user places cursor back and types "h" again name = "John" my contactForm is still dirty even though is in original state?

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder, AbstractControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ContactDetail } from './../../../models/contact-details.model';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'contact-edit-edit-body',
  templateUrl: './contact-edit-edit-body.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-edit-edit-body.component.css']
})
export class ContactEditEditBodyComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() contact: ContactDetail = new ContactDetail(0);

  contactForm: FormGroup;
  name: AbstractControl;
  phoneNumber: AbstractControl;
  emailAddress: AbstractControl;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.contactForm = fb.group({
      "name": [this.contact.name],
      "phoneNumber": [this.contact.phoneNumber],
      "emailAddress": [this.contact.emailAddress]
    });

    this.name = this.contactForm.controls['name'];
    this.phoneNumber = this.contactForm.controls['phoneNumber'];
    this.emailAddress = this.contactForm.controls['emailAddress'];
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Comment: The dirty property indicates that the user has interacted with the form, not a difference in data. If you programmatically change the data, the form will still be in the pristine state. To track your 'true' state, you can listen to the valueChanges of the form and check if you data is still the same en set the form pristine

Comment: Not really true this, if I tab through a form it will remain dirty = false? Is tabbing not interaction?

Comment: I think I confused dirty/pristine with touched state there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can think of is a hackish ways perhaps, but it does what you want. Just have some change event that we can match if the values match:

```
<input formControlName="name" (input)="check(contact.name, name)"/>
```

```ts
check(val, formCtrl) {
  val === formCtrl.value ? formCtrl.markAsPristine() : ''
}
```

We can listen to form changes and then check if the [objects match](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html), and if so mark the form as pristine:

```ts
this.contactForm.valueChanges
  .subscribe(values => {
    this.isEquivalent(this.contact, values)
});

isEquivalent(a, b) {
  let aProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
  let bProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);

  for (var i = 0; i < aProps.length; i++) {
    let propName = aProps[i];

    if (a[propName] !== b[propName]) {
        return false;
    }
  }
  this.contactForm.markAsPristine()
}
```

PS, I'm happy to see if someone comes up with better ideas :)